# Issues identifying missing data with no NA in time series

Tags: r

I'm working with a time series database that has no NA, what I mean by that is that after a row that should have missing data or an NA the column that tracks times jumps to the next value without recording the time stamp of the NA. for example:

time - value

1 - 50kg

2 - 60kg

4- 45kg

there is no recording of the NA, but it is implicit or perhaps a pattern that there's missing data, is ther a good package to handle this kind of missing data?I've tried using 'naniar', but it doesn't work if I don't have NAs

I'm looking for a package that identifies this and imputes the missing data

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO,  Luis Barbosa! A good first question. A minor request: the Stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect, please verify the tags it recommends as relevant. In this case, the [tag:rstudio] tag says *"DO NOT use this tag for general R programming problems"*, not to be used unless the question is explicitly about the IDE; and the [tag:cran] tag is meant for questions about the *"central repository for R distributions"*, not about general R questions. I've removed both. Thanks!

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and note that it asks to provide reproducible input using `dput` so that anyone else can copy and paste it from the question to their session.

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with this is to create a frame of "all times" (even the missing ones) and then `merge` it back in.

```r
dat <- data.frame(time = c(1L, 2L, 4L), value = c(50, 60, 45))
dat
#   time value
# 1    1    50
# 2    2    60
# 3    4    45
times <- data.frame(time = seq(min(dat$time), max(dat$time), by = 1))
times
#   time
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    3
# 4    4
merge(dat, times, by = "time", all = TRUE)
#   time value
# 1    1    50
# 2    2    60
# 3    3    NA
# 4    4    45
```

I included a more-verbose call to `seq` with `by=` in case your real data has a slightly-different structure. For instance, if those are `POSIXt`, then you may want to change that to be `by="1 day"` or `by="1 hour"`. Either way, you control the gaps there.

For more information about merges, see [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) and [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272).

(This gets a little more complicated if the interval between rows is inconsistent, or if the real `time` variables are not aligned perfectly on an integer-like component.)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you have -- a text file with literally the text shown?  a data frame? other? so we will assume that we have `Lines` copied verbatim from the question in the Note at the end except we added one more row.

Read it into a `zoo` series using `read.zoo` as such objects can represent irregularly spaced series. (`read.zoo` can also read files and data frames.)   Next, convert that to a `ts` series which can only represent regularly spaced series and so the conversion causes the empty spots to be filled with NA's.  Then use `na.locf` (last occurrence carried forward), `na.approx` (linear interpolation) or `na.spline` (spline interpolation) to fill in the NA's.  Leave it as a `ts` series or convert it back to a `zoo` series using `as.zoo` or to a data frame using `fortify.zoo`.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "-", strip.white = TRUE,
  comment.char = "k")

tt <- as.ts(z)
na.approx(tt)
## Time Series:
## Start = 1 
## End = 5 
## Frequency = 1 
## [1] 50.0 60.0 52.5 45.0 46.0
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "time - value
1 - 50kg
2 - 60kg
4- 45kg
5 - 46kg"
```